# LinkedIn API: get picture without linkedin watermark

Tags: linkedin-api

When using `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~` (on behalf of the user, then), we can retrieve the user profile picture, but it has a LinkedIn watermark on it.

As we would like to automate most things for the user if they choose to sign up using LinkedIn, including defining their profile picture, we do not want the LinkedIn logo on it (by the way, the picture is the user's property, not LinkedIn's)

Is it possible to retrieve the picture without the logo? The same way unregistered visitors can see it whenever they visit the user profile...

It is really weird that anonymous visitors can access the unmarked user's picture, whereas we can't do it officially on behalf of the said user.

Comment: The picture may be the user's property, but the API is LinkedIn's. If they don't offer it, you will have to get it directly from the user.